# Cran R loop error on second iteration - getting all NAs

Tags: r, for-loop, fread, read.csv

I have a loop going through each file in a directory. It works fine on one file, but as soon as there are 2 or more files in the directory, the second (or more) output is all NAs.

I've tried switching from read.csv to fread, I've tried converting .csv to .txt, I have tried different methods of selecting specific columns (e.g., keeps, select), but I always get NAs for the second time through the loop. It is not the second file, because if I remove the first file, the second is processed perfectly.

Not sure if it is something at the end of the .csv, or if it is adding rownames to the second file or what. Thanks!

```
filenames <- list.files()
n_filenames <- length(filenames)
SSRT_cb1_pre <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = n_filenames)) 
cols <- c(13, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 31, 32)
for (i in 1:n_filenames) {
  print(filenames)
  dt_pre <- fread(filenames[i], header=T, sep=",", select=cols, 
        stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings=c("NA", "", "."))
  dt_pre$RT <- as.numeric(dt_pre$rt)
  data_real_pre <- subset(dt_pre, SSTBlocks.thisRepN>=0)
  data_corr_pre <- subset(data_real_pre, corr == 1)
  data_corr_pre_RTmean <- aggregate(RT ~ P, data = data_corr_pre, 
       FUN=mean, na.rm=TRUE) 
  data_corr_pre_SSDmean <- aggregate(SSD ~ P, data = data_corr_pre, 
   FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE) 
  pre_sub <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i,1]
  preMeanRT <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i,2]
  preMeanSSD  <- data_corr_pre_SSDmean[i,2]   
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 1] <- i
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 2] <- pre_sub
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 3] <- preMeanRT
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 4] <- preMeanSSD
}
SSRT_cb1_pre
```

The following gives me this output:

Outputs:

```
SSRT_cb1_pre

i sub1     preRT    preSSD
1 1  301 0.4877872 0.2580645
2 2   NA        NA        NA
```

NEWER CODE THAN ABO

```
filenames <- list.files()
n_filenames <- length(filenames)
n_rows <- n_filenames/2
SSRT_cb1_pre <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = n_filenames)) # for output
colnames(SSRT_cb1_pre) <- c("i","sub1", "preRT", "preSSD")
cols <- c(13, 23, 24, 25, 28, 29, 31, 32)
colsnames <- c("SSTBlocks.thisRepN", "SSD", "corr", "rt", "sess", "CB", "P", "expName")

for (i in 1:n_filenames) {

  print(filenames)
  dt_pre <- fread(filenames[i], header=T, sep=",", select=colsnames, stringsAsFactors=F, na.strings=c("NA", "", "."))
  dt_pre$RT <- as.numeric(dt_pre$rt)
  data_real_pre <- subset(dt_pre, SSTBlocks.thisRepN>=0)
  data_corr_pre <- subset(data_real_pre, corr == 1)
  data_corr_pre_RTmean <- data_corr_pre[, mean(RT, na.rm=T), by = P] #suggested by Yannis Vassiliadis Stackoverflow as alt to aggregate 
  data_corr_pre_SSDmean <- data_corr_pre[, mean(SSD, na.rm=T), by = P] 
  # values to collect from each file
  pre_sub <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i, 1]
  preMeanRT <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i, 2]
  preMeanSSD  <- data_corr_pre_SSDmean[i, 2]   
 # output for values - should iterate through 
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 1] <- i
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 2] <- pre_sub
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 3] <- preMeanRT
  SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 4] <- preMeanSSD

}

SSRT_cb1_pre
class(data_corr_pre_RTmean)
class(data_corr_pre_SSDmean)
```

This gives the out put of:

```
[1] "301_1_PsychoPy_SST_Pretest_2.csv" "303_1_PsychoPy_SST_Pretest.csv"  
[1] "301_1_PsychoPy_SST_Pretest_2.csv" "303_1_PsychoPy_SST_Pretest.csv"  
Warning messages:
1: In as.numeric(dt_pre$rt) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In as.numeric(dt_pre$rt) : NAs introduced by coercion
> 
> SSRT_cb1_pre
  i sub1     preRT    preSSD
1 1  301 0.4877872 0.2580645
2 2   NA        NA        NA
> class(data_corr_pre_RTmean)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
> class(data_corr_pre_SSDmean)
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"
```

Comment: Thanks - I wish it were that simple, but the spaces or no spaces didn't change a thing.

Comment: I have a feeling that you would avoid the error if you used columns names instead of column indexes. The `select` argument of `fread` accepts characters as well. As an aside, given that `dt_pre` and `data_real_pre` have class `data.table`, I suggest you use `dt_corr_pre[, mean(RT, na.rm=T), by = P]` as a faster alternative to `aggregate`.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help. It doesn't seem to matter whether or not I reference column names or column index. I did just notice though, that while when i=1, the values pass correctly into SSRT_cb1_pre but when i = 2 they pass as NA, when I check the variable holding the calculated means for i = 2, they are correctly stored in data_corr_pre_RTmean and data_corr_pre_SSDmean, so they are just not passing to the new data.frame SSRT_cb1_pre.

Comment: So, assuming that `P` takes on more than 1 values *in each file*, then `data_corr_pre_RTmean` and `data_corr_pre_SSDmean` are data frames. Then for the 2nd file, you get the 2nd row of `data_corr_pre_RTmean` and create `preMeanRT`. But if the 2nd row doesn't exist, it means that `P` only takes one value, i.e. you shouldn't even be using `aggregate`, just `mean`.

Comment: Thanks Yannis - I have now modified my code (see above) and yes - those variables are data.table/data.frame, but still are not passing the second set of means (eventually I will have many more files but and just trying to work out these kinks), but they are being generated and stored. Is there something that I need to change about either: SSRT_cb1_pre <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 4, nrow = n_filenames)); or  preMeanRT <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i, 2]; or   SSRT_cb1_pre[i, 3] <- preMeanRT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In absence of reproducible example I can't test it but I think you should change below code

```
pre_sub <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i,1]
preMeanRT <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[i,2]
preMeanSSD  <- data_corr_pre_SSDmean[i,2]
```

to

```
pre_sub <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[,1]
preMeanRT <- data_corr_pre_RTmean[,2]
preMeanSSD <- data_corr_pre_SSDmean[,2]
```

Comment: THAT'S IT!!!!  removing the i in data_corr_pre_RTmean[i,1] did it. thank you SO much.